# Connect 2 Android devices using Bluetooth Serial

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, bluetooth

Is it possible connecting 2 android phones with Bluetooth and share/send data to another Android phone
and sends back a response after receiving and reading the data.

The idea is to send data/share data offline using Bluetooth on Android to Android Phone/tablet

Below is my environment
Ionic:
Ionic CLI                     : 6.20.1
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.2.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 13.0.4
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 13.0.4
@angular/cli                  : 13.0.4
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 5.0.3

Cordova:
Cordova CLI       : 11.0.0
Cordova Platforms : android 10.1.2
Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 14 other plugins)

Utility:
cordova-res                          : 0.15.4
native-run (update available: 1.7.1) : 1.5.0

System:
NodeJS : v14.15.4 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
npm    : 6.14.10
OS     : Windows 10